# didSet not called by Array.append() in Swift

Tags: swift, append, swiftui, didset

I am following the [100 Days of SwiftUI](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/100/swiftui) and have reached [Day 37](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/100/swiftui/37). While doing [Making changes permanent with UserDefaults](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/books/ios-swiftui/making-changes-permanent-with-userdefaults), I encounter a problem with `didSet`.

(I am using Swift 5 with iOS 13.4)

In the example code, it writes

```
.navigationBarItems(trailing: Button("Save") {
    if let actualAmount = Int(self.amount) {
        let item = ExpenseItem(name: self.name, type: self.type, amount: actualAmount)
        self.expenses.items.append(item)
    }
})
```

where `didSet` should be called by `.append()`.

However, in practice, the `didSet` is not called unless I change the above code to

```
.navigationBarItems(trailing: Button("Save") {
    if let actualAmount = Int(self.amount) {
        let item = ExpenseItem(name: self.name, type: self.type, amount: actualAmount)
        let newItems = self.expenses.items + [item]
        self.expenses.items = newItems
    }
})
```

I also write a small test (see below) in Playground which shows that `.append()` works pretty well with `didSet`

```
struct Count {
    var array: [Int] {
        didSet {
            print("struct Count - didSet() called")
        }
    }
}
class CountClass {
    var array: [Int] {
        didSet {
            print("class CountClass - didSet() called")
        }
    }
    init() {
        array = [1, 2, 3]
    }
}
struct Test {
    var countA = Count(array: [1, 2, 3])
    var countB = CountClass()

    mutating func testDidSet() {
        countA.array.append(4)
        countB.array.append(4)
    }
}

var t = Test()
t.testDidSet()
```

This strange behaviour really makes me wonder how `didSet` works. Or is this problem related to the use of `@ObservedObject` (which is the case of the example project)?

PS: I have downloaded the finished version from [Project7](https://github.com/twostraws/HackingWithSwift/tree/master/SwiftUI/project7) and it also has the problem.

Comment: State or Published property wrappers use "will set" behavior.

Comment: duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60130373/ios-13-4-didset-not-called-anymore-for-a-published-bool-when-using-toggle

Comment: @Chris it is not duplicate, even though i agree that it is the same misunderstanding how SwiftUI works.

Comment: @user3441734 I change `didSet` to `willSet`, still not working ... I also tried to change the whole `ExpenseItem` and `Expenses` to a dummy `Int` value wrapped in another dummy class and it works well with `=`. It really makes me wonder that if `didSet` and `willSet` only works for `=` ... sigh...

Comment: Don't move from the right way! You already played with willSet and didSet property observers. There is no "strange behavior" or some "problem related" to using ObservedObject property wrapper.  Try to avoid mixing different strategies (at least at the beginning) and follow some Apple tutorial. SwiftUI is a new concept, a new paradigm.  Most trouble (even experienced swift programmer could have often) is missing documentation

Answer (score 4):

This is a known Swift 5.2 bug: observers of wrapped properties are not called upon modification (https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-12089). They had known about this since January and all the same released an update breaking a bunch of production code ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

A temporary workaround is already presented in the question - property reassignment instead of modification.

Answer (score 0):

I went through this project as well. Make sure your `items` property in the `Expenses` class is marked as `@Published`. As below;

```
import SwiftUI

struct ExpenseItem: Identifiable, Codable {
let id = UUID()
let name: String
let type: String
let amount: Int
}

class Expenses: ObservableObject {
init() {
    if let items = UserDefaults.standard.data(forKey: "Items") {
        let decoder = JSONDecoder()
        if let decoded = try? decoder.decode([ExpenseItem].self, from: items)     {
            self.items = decoded
            return
        }
    }
    self.items = []
}


@Published var items: [ExpenseItem] {
    didSet {
        let encoder = JSONEncoder()
        if let encoded = try? encoder.encode(items) {
            UserDefaults.standard.set(encoded, forKey: "Items")
        }
    }
}
}
```

and add `self.presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()` in your navigation bar Save button.

```
.navigationBarItems(trailing: Button("Save") {
            if let actualAmount = Int(self.amount) {
                let item = ExpenseItem(name: self.name, type: self.type,   amount: actualAmount)
                self.expenses.items.append(item)
                self.presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
            } else {
                self.isShowingAlert = true
            }

        })
```

Comment: I have finished the whole project following the tutorial but I don't think `@Publilsh` and `self.presentationMode.wrappedValue.dissmiss()` will solve the problem. The final project posted on Github fails as well ...

Answer (score 0):

I finished this project last week I think, but checking the [Swift GitHub page](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#swift-52) it seems there was an update on the 24th.

When I did this project everything worked fine, but now I'm on day 47 and I'm having this very problem. Maybe it's related to the Swift 5.2 update.

Comment: I have to say that you kind of ruin my day since I'm on Day 46 and about to move on to Day 47 ... really hate it when something "wrong" has to be done just to fix a bug ...

Answer (score 0):

What's happening is that Swift is not recognizing the `.append()` as setting the variable. You can get around this by copying your array to a new temporary array, append the new value and then set your class array to this temporary array.

```
var newActivityList = [Activity]() //new temporary array
for activity in self.activityList.activities {
    newActivityList.append(activity) //copy class array to temp array
}
newActivityList.append(newActivity) //append new value

self.activityList.activities = newActivityList //set class array to temp array
```

PS: the example above is for day 47, but the logic is the same.